# How many segments a process can have in operating system employing Segmentation for memory management

Tags: operating-systems

**Some facts about "Segmented Paging"**

1)  Each process has one segment table.
2)  There is one-page table per segment.

**Fact about "Paged segmentation"**

3)  Contains page table of segment table.

**Now consider following problem**

> In a paged segmented scheme of memory management, the segment table itself must have a page table because. 
>   (A)  The segment table is often too large to fit in one page.
>   (B)  Each segment is spread over a number of pages.
>   (C)  Segment tables point to page tables and not to the physical locations of the segment.
>   (D)  The processor’s description base register points to a page table

**Given solution is:**

Here option (A) is true , as segment table are sometimes too large to keep in one pages. So, segment table divided into pages. Thus page table for each Segment Table pages are created.

**My Doubt**

I believe a page can contain several hundreds of segment table entries of form

```
  <segment base, limit>
```

I only came across code, data, stack and heap segments. I believe a process can have only these  "four" segments. And also, we know each process has a segment table (Fact 1). Then how a segment table can grow so large that it cannot be fitted in a single page?

Answer (score 1):

A process can only access 6 segments simultaneously through `CS`, `SS`, `DS`, `ES`, `FS`, and `GS` registers on an x86 and x86-64 machines.

These registers point to an entry in the segment descriptor table that the operating system manages. If OS uses a **multi-segment memory model** then that table can have an arbitrary size thus allowing a process to access a theoretically unlimited number of segments. ([Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/ia32/IA32-3A.pdf) 3-6 Vol.3)

Answer (score 0):

I referenced [Galvin](https://www.amazon.in/Operating-System-Principles-Silberschatz/dp/8126509627/) and found this:

> Normally, when a program is compiled, the compiler automatically constructs
>   segments reflecting the input program.
>   A C compiler might create separate segments for the following:
>
> 1. The code
> 2. Global variables
> 3. The heap, from which memory is allocated
> 4. The stacks used by each thread
> 5. The standard C library
>
> Libraries that are linked in during compile time might be assigned separate
>   segments. The loader would take all these segments and assign them segment
>   numbers.

This explains how there can be multiple segments per process enough to grow the segment table so large that it cannot be fitted in a single page.

**Further doubt:**

From this, I can understand there can be multiple code segments each one for each referenced library. I was guessing if there can be multiple stack, heap and data segments. If yes, when?

Comment: If you have several threads, each one has it's own stack, at least. They might share heap, or have their own.

Comment: If you have a further question, please ask it separately. You can certainly reference the original question that prompted yours.

Comment: so its fixed, right? : one thread can have at max one stack? Yes I can understand that heap usually stores global variables, so its shared among various threads. But still I am guessing can there be any odd situation where a process can have multiple heap segments?

Comment: As far as I can see (check your friendly assembler/linker manual for details), there is no (or only a ridiculously high) limit to the number of segments in a process. Which makes sense if you want to have shared libraries: each library is loaded separately into memory (thus sharable), and your program can certainly use a large set of disparate libraries (for C++, base C, the Boost libraries, handle a GUI, and furthermore handle e.g. a set of different formats of video/images, each with it's own library).